# How to make this jquery pagination work with my perl application

Tags: jquery, perl, pagination

For sometime I have been looking for an adequate solution to my pagination woes, my following perl script does work however it creates page links in hundreds which looks very odd, I need a compact one and for this I have come across a site which provides the solution I am looking for but the help is very scanty and I am not a jquery person, I have been googling around to see if I can use this jquery script myself but could not find helpful hints therefore I am here at OverFlow to seek your assistance in integrating this jquery plugin with my code.

[Here](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?Gs38DrL4) is the jquery code and demo that I mentioned above.

If you know jquery but don't have time right now, please mark it for later when you have time, but please do help, I have seen threads here full of codes provided by you experts.

Here is my script:

```
# Count how many rows are there in a table, so that we can use it for $pagenum.  
    my $sql = qq!SELECT COUNT(*) from "Orders" !;  
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare ("$sql");  
    $sth->execute() || quit();  
    my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array;       
    $sth->finish;  

# Setting  offset, limit and page number 

    my $offset = 0;  
    my $limit = 8;  
    my $pagenum = ceil($row[0]/$limit);  

# Assigning value to $offset as 0 or whatever will be the $pagenum i.e. 1 or 2 .... 

    $offset=param('page')? $limit*param('page') :0;  

# Get the data 

    $sql = qq!SELECT  
             a."OrderID", b."CompanyName" AS "CustomerName",   
             c."FirstName"::text || ' ' ||c."LastName"::text AS "EmployeeName",  
             a."OrderDate"::DATE, a."RequiredDate"::DATE, a."ShippedDate"::DATE,  
             d."CompanyName" AS "ShipVia", a."Freight", a."ShipName",   
             a."ShipAddress", a."ShipCity", a."ShipRegion",  
             a."ShipPostalCode", a."ShipCountry"   
         FROM  
             "Orders" a, "Customers" b, "Employees" c, "Shippers" d  
         WHERE  
             a."CustomerID" = b."CustomerID" AND  
             a."EmployeeID" = c."EmployeeID" AND  
             a."ShipVia"    = d."ShipperID"  
         ORDER BY 1  
         LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset !;  

    $sth=$dbh->prepare("$sql");  
    $sth->execute() || quit(); 

#.... then html stuff skiped.... 

# Showing page number with link 

    my $first_page = $pagenum - $pagenum ;  
    my $last_page = $pagenum - 1;  
    $pagenum = $pagenum - 1;  

    print q(<ul class="tsc_pagination tsc_paginationA tsc_paginationA09">);  
    print qq(<li><a href='vieword.pl?page=$first_page'>First>);  
    for my $i (0 .. $pagenum)  
    {  
    print qq(<li><a href='vieword.pl?page=$i'>$i>);  
    }  
    print qq(<li><a href='vieword.pl?page=$last_page'>Last>);  
    print q(</ul>);
```

Many many thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First declare :

```
my $reqpage = $q->param('reqpage') || '1';
```

and then add the following in the body section of your script :

```
            <script src="js/jquery.paginate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            \$(function() {

                    \$("#demo2").paginate({
                            count           : $your_page_count,
                            start           : $reqpage,
                            onChange        : function(reqpage) {
                                 location.href =  'your_script.pl?reqpage='+ reqpage;},
                            display         : 27,
                            border                  : false,
                            text_color              : '#303030',
                            background_color        : '#EEE',       
                            text_hover_color        : 'black',
                            background_hover_color  : '#CFCFCF'
                    });
                    });
            </script>
```